# delete record from elastic search using typescript with node js

Tags: node.js, typescript, elasticsearch

I am new to elastic search. I am using elastic search version 7.4.0. I am able to create and update record in elastic search by using @elastic/elasticsearch npm package. I am using node js with typescript. When I am trying to delete record from elastic search it is giving me "Response Error". I am not getting what is wrong here. Below is my code.

```
import { Client, ApiResponse, RequestParams } from "@elastic/elasticsearch";

export class ElasticSearchService {

    public async deleteIndex (index: string, id: string): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise<any>(async (resolve: any, reject: any) => {
            try {
                const doc1: RequestParams.Delete = {
                    index: index,
                    id: id
                };
                let result: ApiResponse = await client.delete(doc1);
                resolve(result);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch');
const client = new Client({ node: 'http://localhost:9200' });

export class ElsastricSearch {


    deleteData = async (index: string, type: string, id: string ) => {
        return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {

           let result =   await  client.delete({
                   index: index,
                   type: type,
                   id: id,
               });
           resolve(result);
            } catch (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    };

}
```

I have tested typeScript and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

```
const data: RequestParams.Delete = {
            index: <<IndexName>>,
            id: <<ElasticId>>,
        }
        await client.delete(data);
```

Comment: Consider explaining the root cause of the problem and the solution. It'll improve both the OP and you.